# What is the difference between en/eis for Pauline "Faith in Christ" phrases?

Tags: greek, paul, faith

Paul has several different phrases which all translate "Faith in Christ".  This question pertains to the difference in meaning for **faith in Christ** where the English word "in" has a direct Greek word, either "en" or "eis".  Is there a difference in the meaning when these greek words are used, or are they basically interchangeable?

For "en" it seems to indicate located or resting in, which means an active connection to Christ which allows, causes, or provides the faith.  If that is correct, then what is the meaning of "eis" in the phrase?

Checking a couple versions, I can't find any that change "in" to "into" or "on" for either "en" or "eis".

**Note:** I am specifically excluding phrases for "pistis Christos" in this question, which do not contain the en/eis greek word as a connector, and can be translated either **faith in Christ** or **faith/faithfulness of Christ**.

**Usage of "en":**

> **"en" (Strong's 1718)**
>   **Word Origin:** a primary preposition denoting (fixed) position (in place, time or state), and (by implication) instrumentality (medially or constructively), i.e. a relation of rest (intermediate between (1519) and (1537))
>   **Definition** 1. in, by, with etc
>
> **2 Tim 3:15 [NET]** and how from infancy you have known the holy writings, which are able to give you wisdom for salvation through **faith in [en] Christ Jesus**.
>
> **Col 1:4 [NET]**  since we heard about your **faith in [en] Christ Jesus** and the love that you have for all the saints.

**Usage of "eis":**

> **"eis" (Strong's #1519)**
>   **Word Origin:**  A primary preposition
>   **Definition:**  1. into, unto, to, towards, for, among
>
> **Col 2:5 [NET]** For though I am absent from you in body, I am present with you in spirit, rejoicing to see your morale and the firmness of your **faith in [eis] Christ**.

---

Edited to remove the Acts 24:24 example of eis and narrow focus to Paul's usage.  Really interested in specifically understanding en/eis usage specific to the phrase "Faith in Christ" by Paul.  There is some related treatment of "believe in him" in [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/9250/11226), but not a really clear answer of the en/eis difference even there.

Comment: FYI, the LSJ lexicon entries for "en" and "eis" respectively are available here:  http://logeion.uchicago.edu/%E1%BC%90%CE%BD    http://logeion.uchicago.edu/%CE%B5%E1%BC%B0%CF%82

Comment: @Ruminator - thanks for that resource. Looking at the lexicon entries, Is this as simple as "en" typically having an immediate sense (it is "located in" the room right now, at this moment), and "eis" having a more directional or continuous sense (I "am going into" the room), in other words, it denotes a change of state or action toward/into something, rather than a state that already exists?  For example, in Gal 2:16 "we believed in Christ" denotes moving from a state of not believing, to one of believing?

Comment: Being "in" Christ is a major Pauline theme. The believer doesn't just believe facts about Christ but becomes joined to him and become members of his body. So "believe eis Christ" is to believe that he died for your sins and thus become a part of his body. Faith en Christ is static trusting and being in him. I think you have the right idea.

Answer (score 1):

G1722 en is a preposition of rest within a domain or sphere, including the idea of being in union with it. As K Wuest would sometimes render it, "in the realm of" or "in the sphere of", etc. So if it s "en Christō", then I often like to translate these Pauline phrases like this: "within and in union with the Anointed Ruler Who governs by giving Himself like lamp oil to burns to create light". We are in vital union with Christ, where His life is unto us as oil, even of the same "phreneo" / regulation like in Php 2:4-11, where we give ourselves away too. That is what I think Paul means when he only wants to know Christ and Him crucified to the Corinthians. Bottom line: "en" is a preposition of relational union, which is also the basic reality of the dative case.

G1519 eis is a preposition of motion that penetrates into something. With "eis", an implied verb or adverb is helpful in English due to the implied motion. Examples might be (focused) into, (directed) into, (going into). So with Col 2:5, here is my on the fly translation:

*"**If, I am indeed sent-away-and-absent by, with, in the flesh, yet-rather-on-this-other I exist jointly-with you-folks by, with, in the spirit, I am continually delighting in grace and looking-and-observing your orderly-arrangement** (like a well-oiled machine) **and** (the) **effect-of-**(your)-**rock-solid belonging to your life-alignment-and-congruent-heart** (directed) **into-the-midst-of** (The) **Anointed-One-**(Who gives Himself like oil gives itself to burn up so that others may have light)."*

Existing in the Spirit effectively means unshakable-ness. Faith is living, thus it is active, like a branch staying focused into the trunk-vine. That is why I prefer "life-alignment or heart congruency or sharing God's view. Bottom line: it is an "into the midst of" reality.

I think all those translation that stick with "faith in Christ" can easily be construed to mean something different in English than what Paul meant. We need to maintain a heart focused on and into Christ The Living One - like Heb 12:1-2. We set our heart above where Christ is seated, because we have been raised with Him (Col 3:1). The point in Col 3 is that, we live on earth, but we are really dead and Christ is our life (Col 3:3-4). So that is the focus we lean into. Thus, we put away the old (Col 3:5).

Answer (score -1):

Paul seems to like the “into Christ” usage more than any other writer. He also was the only writer to proclaim “my gospel” also. More intimacy is shown by him through his being in Christ example as to just a knowledge of Christ. Vital truth of a valid claim to union with Christ! Well done!

Comment: Hi Dan - welcome to the site.  Unfortunately, I downvoted, as I do not see how this answers the question posed. It does not attempt to explain the difference between "en" and "eis" in the phrase "Faith in (en/eis) Christ" in Paul's writings.

Answer (score -4):

### Looking at the Greek

**Colossians 1:4**

`ἀκούσαντες   |  τὴν   | πίστιν |  ὑμῶν  | ἐν | χριστῷ | Ἰησοῦ`
`upon hearing | of the | faith  | of you | in | Christ | Jesus`

Which gives:

> upon hearing of your faith in Jesus Christ

**Colossians 2:5**

`τὸ  | στερέωμα | τῆς | εἰς  | χριστὸν | πίστεως | ὑμῶν`
`the | strength | of  | into | Christ  | faith   | your`

Which gives:

> the strength of your faith into-Christ

OR

> the strength of your into-Christ faith

There are no instances of πίστεως (pisteos) in the Gospels. The first time we see it used is in reference to Steven in Acts 6:5, which leads me to believe that πίστεως (pisteos) is faith that comes by the indwelling Holy Spirit. This is confirmed by what Paul says in:

**2 Corinthians 1:21**

`Ὁ   |  δὲ |       βεβαιῶν       | ἡμᾶς |      σὺν      | ὑμῖν`
`The | now | is making steadfast |  us  | together with | you(s)`
`εἰς  | χριστόν | καὶ |   χρίσας   | ἡμᾶς | θεός`
`into | Christ  | and | annointing |  us  | God`

Which gives:

> Now, he who makes us steadfast with you into-Christ and annoints us, is God.

### Addendum

en: τὴν πίστιν ὑμῶν ἐν χριστῷ (the faith of you **in** Christ). "en" is used where the "faith" spoken of is more like "belief". It can be a strong belief, as any instance from the Gospels might show. For example:

**Matthew 8:10**

> When Jesus heard it, He marveled, and said to those who followed, "Assuredly, I say to you, I have not found such great faith (πίστιν - pistin), not even in Israel!"

However,

eis: τῆς εἰς χριστὸν πίστεως (faith **into** Christ) is structurally different. In grammatical terms we have τῆς (genitive article) εἰς (prep) χριστὸν (noun) πίστεως (genitive noun).

In English when two nouns are used together, the first acts as an adjective for the second. For example, Mathematics Teacher - "Oh! So, you're a teacher? What kind of teacher?" The noun, Mathematics, is used to modify the noun, Teacher.

Now, the preposition εἰς (eis) is adding a degree of intimacy, here - τῆς εἰς χριστὸν πίστεως ὑμῶν (your faith into-Christ/your into-Christ faith).
In Galatians 2:16 we have:

> knowing that a man is not justified by the works of the law but by faith in Jesus Christ, even we have believed in Christ Jesus, that we might be justified by faith in Christ and not by the works of the law; for by the works of the law no flesh shall be justified.

It's not "even we have believed in (en) Christ" but "even we have believed **into** (eis) Christ". It's that sense of intimacy again that communicates the "faith" Paul is speaking of is something more than just "belief".

Reiterating from above: the use of πίστεως doesn't appear in the Gospels. It first appeared in Acts 6:5, this was after the Holy Spirit was given. It is describing a faith that is not possible for a person who has not been born again. So what was spoken of as simply "faith **in** (en) Christ" before Pentecost, became "faith **into** (eis) Christ" after.

For those who don't believe in such things as "being born again", you have to take the view that the authors of the text did, which has significant implications for any interpretation you might make. To understand what has been written, you have to dismiss any feeling that the subject matter might appear to you as nonsense.

### Conclusion

Paul's use of "faith **in** (en) Christ", which had the pre-Pentecost sense of "belief" in Christ, as strong as that may have been, is distinct from his use of "faith **into** (ein) Christ" (or even "into-Christ faith"), which is a new construction that evokes a sense of intimacy (bond) with Christ that the earlier form couldn't express.

Comment: I haven't voted yet, but I think you didn't really answer the question, though I like the research (I'm pretty much a layman on the greek).  Specifically, in Col 1:4 you just reverted the English back to "faith in Christ", which is extremely muddy, and then didn't explain how that really differs from eis in Col 2:5, which you give as "into-Christ faith".  What is the difference?  That is the original question.  On the last section, how does the extra passage enlighten the Col 2:5 "eis" usage?  It's difficult to follow your reasoning and conclusion(s).

Comment: I thought it was obvious from the construction. I will add to the answer to make it more so.

Comment: I DVed because *pisteos* and *pistin* are inflections of the same lexeme; this answer rests on the idea that the former has a different *lexical* meaning. That the syntax of the genitive case is limited to Acts + Epistles is actually a fascinating bit of information that, IMO, deserves further analysis in terms of the prepositions and nominal constructions that govern *pistis*, but that is neither the topic of this question (which is rather  about the prepositions governing the **object** of *pistis*) nor part of this answer.

Comment: I don't follow the relevance, but "Mathematics Teacher" is not an adjective construction but a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Comment: @Susan I will bow to your superior knowledge on such things, but you are just picking nits. Whatever the structure is called, its function is clearly as I've described it.

Comment: @Susan. From your link: "***Adjectival noun is a term that was formerly synonymous with noun adjunct** but is now usually used to mean "an adjective used as a noun" (i.e. the opposite process, as in the Irish meaning "Irish people" or the poor meaning "poor people"). Japanese adjectival nouns are a different concept.*" Meanings of terms change over time.

Comment: `the opposite process`

Comment: It is NOW the opposite process, but it was FORMERLY synonymous. Thank you for bringing me up to date. It has no bearing on the answer.

Comment: @enegue Thanks for the updated answer, though I will need some time to dig into your commentary.  I believe this line of reasoning will require bringing in the non-eis and non-en "faith in Christ"/"Faith of Christ" passages as well.  I'm still confused about the en/eis usage, because it appears to completely ignore the object of the faith, it seems an assumption that the reader is already aware of that, and in these passages the source, location, or connectedness of the faith is the primary attribute Paul is bringing to light.

Comment: One thing that you don't seem to address in your answer is the idea of actually being *in Christ*. You seem to conclude that "into" (eis) is used by Paul only to indicate "intimacy" but there are many, myself included, conclude that the believer is, at least metaphorically, "incorporated into Christ" as "members of his body". I'm not aware of any grammar that relegates the preposition to being an indicator of intimacy. Thoughts?

Comment: @Ruminator What happened to your previous comments and my responses?

Comment: I delete my comments after they are read. They aren't designed to be part of the answer. Answers should incorporate anything that is part of the answer rather than being left in comments. I don't know anything about your comments being deleted.

Comment: What about "faith toward Christ"? I'd sure like to see some suggestion in a lexicon that eis is a marker of intimacy.

Comment: @Ruminator I struggle to wonder what faith "toward" anything would mean. Faith means trust - how can I trust "toward" something? i.e. I understand faith in a bridge, that I trust it will hold the weight put on it, but toward a bridge?  Maybe with Christ being a person, Lord, head of the church, etc., it might apply?  Also, I do believe, as you mention, that one of the meanings (or both) *could* be "incorporated into", but I'm not sure that fits either - I am incorporated into Christ, but is my faith? Or is it my faith incorporated into his? Etc.

Comment: True, "faith toward" isn't English. But "eis is more intimacy" is not Greek, at least in any text I'm aware of.